# Why when I open my files in ubuntu 16.04, are hidden files always displayed?

Tags: ubuntu

Whenever I open my files in ubuntu, hidden files appear.

How can I do that when opening my files, the hidden files are not displayed by default?

THX!

Comment: uh... what is the context? where is this happening?

Comment: @thrig First guess is often the right one, let's bet ;-) ...

Comment: That question terribly looks like another one, **14** days ago, almost identical, suspiciously enough, which was answered. Did you perform some *search*, at least?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you're talking about some graphical file manager*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> once. Now your file manager shouldn't show hidden files next time you run it. Beware there *might* be an option in the application's preferences/settings that forces hidden files to be displayed at start.